# java.lang.NullPointerException ,at Annotaion_testng.Login_case.login(Login_case.java:34

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng-eclipse

```
package Annotaion_testng;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login_case {

  public String baseUrl = "https://www.eventerprise.com";
  String driverpath = "C://Users//fizan//Documents//testing//webdriver_soft//fire_fox_driver//geckodriver.exe";
  public WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("opening firefox");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverpath);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }

  @Test
  public void login(){
    System.out.println("click on login link from header");

    //code is failing from here
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/header/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("fijan@atyantik.com");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //enter  password

    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("atyantik@1234");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //click on login button

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eve-modal']/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[4]/button")).click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //click on log out from header

    System.out.println("logging out");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div/header/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a")).click();  
  }
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you getting, which line? Show us relevant HTML block, provide more information, so we can help you

Comment: Ignore my previous (now deleted) comment. As provided in the answer of @ScaryWombat, you aren't using the class-variable `driver` but instead create a new local variable in your method `f`. So the class-variable `driver` is still null, causing the NPE at `driver.findElement(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing `driver` in `f` `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` As you have already correctly declared this as field, removed the new redeclaration

i.e.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: yes, it is helpful